# Remember to check for "duplicates"!

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Many times, it happens to me: I comment to propose a solution *but* I always forget to check for duplicates questions.
Is it possible to add a clearly visible message (maybe above the text box) which remember that when a comment is about to be posted (eventually for answers too)?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Check for duplicate whats? (comments?)

Comment: @gandalf3 ... questions... effectively, I will add that editing the question. Thanks

Comment: For answers it *may be* could be done (although looks like probably not).. Not for comments I think (at least because where to position that box so it's not annoying? And maybe one is commenting for clarifying?). This is kind of habit which e.g. I tried to create for myself.